# getting error Call to a member function prepare() on null in mongodb db in laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb, jenssegers-mongodb

I am using `mongodb` in laravel v8, to use `mongodb` database i used this `composer require jenssegers/mongodb` library, i am using this library and trying to insert 1 record, with this query `DB::table('users')->insert(array('email'=>'ravi@gmail.com'));`
when i run that query it insert the data in `mongodb` but after then it return this error

```
Call to a member function prepare() on null in file /var/www/html/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 331
```

can anyone please help me how to resolve this error ? any help will be really appreciated

Comment: Did you check the .env file? the configuration was okay? run this command php artisan config:clear

Comment: there is no issue in configuration, data is inserting, but getting error